# How to delete data from a model in LoopBack?

Tags: loopbackjs

Is there a command to delete data from a model in LoopBack? Something like:

```
truncate model
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's in the works, though.

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-workspace/issues/259